# Printing JscrollPane Objects

Tags: java, swing, printing, jpanel, jscrollpane

I've searched online for a method to print from code but I've found suggestions to print text only.
What I really need is to print each elements contained in a jScrollPane. Each element is a jPanel which contains image and texts.

[image]

For example I need to print the 2 panels in the image as they are.
How can I achieve that? Is it possible?

Comment: The short answer is don't, use something like `Jasper Repots` instead.  The much longer and more complicated answer is having you either use `printAll` and render the component to the `Graphics` context of the Printer, which is messy, as you need to maintain information about y offsets for each page, deal with page breaks and possible overlaps :P ... The other solution would be to take each component and calculate it's position on the page, based on the page index, this way you can control the number of components painted to the page and handle page breaks.

Comment: Be warned though, this WILL effect your visual/live component, so you will need to revalidate it once your done (or create an off the screen version) and remember to use `printAll`!!

Answer (score 0):

Use below code:

```
    PrinterJob pj = PrinterJob.getPrinterJob();
    pj.setJobName(" Print Component ");

    pj.setPrintable(new PrintableImpl(comp));

    if (!pj.printDialog()) {
        return;
    }
    try {
        pj.print();
    } catch (PrinterException ex) {
        System.out.println(ex);
    }
```

Where `comp` is your `JScrollPane`'s View. In `PrintableImpl` you can implement your fitting/scaling.